# BoxFit.fitWidth не растягивает SVG на весь экран в ширину

Tags: svg, flutter

Почему `fit: BoxFit.fitWidth` не работает и не растягивает svg на весь экран в ширину.
`BoxFit.fill` тоже ничего не меняет. Ширина svg остается таким, каким и является по дефолту.

```
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: reverse,
          physics: physics,
          primary: primary,
          controller: backgroundScrollController,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/illustrations/cosmosBG1.svg',
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          ),
        ),
        .....
     ],
   );
```

svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)"
   sodipodi:docname="cosmosBG1.svg"
   id="svg1132"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 400 3000">
  <metadata
     id="metadata1138">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs1136" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     inkscape:current-layer="_277_alien_flatline"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-x="952"
     inkscape:cy="2523.9089"
     inkscape:cx="182.65093"
     inkscape:zoom="1.31125"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="true"
     showgrid="false"
     id="namedview1134"
     inkscape:window-height="1057"
     inkscape:window-width="960"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     guidetolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     objecttolerance="10"
     borderopacity="1"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     pagecolor="#ffffff" />
  <g
     data-name="#277_alien_flatline"
     id="_277_alien_flatline">
    <circle
       cx="204.35596"
       cy="825.63385"
       r="4.6100001"
       fill="#ffffff"
       id="circle295" />
    <path
       d="m 204.35596,830.74386 a 5.12,5.12 0 1 1 5.11,-5.12 5.12,5.12 0 0 1 -5.11,5.12 z m 0,-9.23 a 4.12,4.12 0 1 0 4.11,4.11 4.12,4.12 0 0 0 -4.11,-4.11 z"
       fill="#d1d3d4"
       id="path297" />
        ............................
```

Comment: там в svg случайно width не написан ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Указан. height="3000" width="400". Удаляя этм атрибуты результат не изменился.

Comment: внутри svg эти параметры ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Да. а во Flutter width не указан

Comment: тогда удалите внутри svg => width и height но запишите `viewBox="0 0 400 3000"`

Comment: помогло ?......

Comment: @MaximLensky нет

Comment: покажите сюда код svg ни весь а только заголовок

Comment: @MaximLensky добавил

Comment: в этом svg ни чего нету - что надо вывести ?

Comment: @MaximLensky там дальше идут рисунки

Comment: я flutter не знаю но уверяю с svg всё в порядке

Answer (score 0):

Не разобрался в проблеме с `fit: BoxFit.fitWidth` но

Растянул svg используя `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)`

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
      reverse: reverse,
      physics: physics,
      primary: primary,
      controller: backgroundScrollController,
      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/illustrations/cosmosBG1.svg',
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
    ),
```

Comment: А зачем вы в `Stack` используете `SingleChildScrollView`? Если `SingleChildScrollView` заменить на `Container`, то все будет работать правильно.

Comment: @MiT Я использую `SingleChildScrollView`, чтобы использовать `controller`. У меня есть еще `CustomScrollView` откуда я беру `controller.position.pixel`s и присваиваю в  `controller` `SingleChildScrollView` для того, чтобы создать фон.

Comment: как-то странно вы делаете фон... Наверняка есть легче способ)